# How to organize MFCC features?

Tags: audio, mfcc

I have computed 12d-MFCC features on 3 consecutive audio frames, say:

```
For 1st frame: a1 a2 a3 ... a12
For 2nd frame: b1 b2 b3 ... b12
For 3rd frame: c1 c2 c3 ... c12
```

How to organize these MFCC features, in `a1 a2 ... a12 b1 b2 ... b12 c1 c2 ... c12` or `a1 b1 c1 ... a12 b12 c12`? Is there any difference between these two organization styles (for audio processing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural order would be to save it on frame by frame basis - that's the way you calculate them, otherwise you would need some gymnastics to do so. What's more, each 12 coefficients will be one vector in your 12D space - frame after frame.

Also it is easier to manage that in memory. In MATLAB like environments you simply use the matrices to store each vector in separate column. For C++, you can use array and array of pointers:

```
float **frames;
float  *data;
frames = new float*[num_frames];
data   = new float*[12 * num_frames];
memset(..)
```

After that you just set all `frames` pointers to first coefficient in each frame and you have easy way to access your features by using `frames`.

With interleaved features it wouldn't be so easy.

Comment: Please don't promote heavily outdated C++ style. We use `std::vector<std::array<float,3>>` nowadays. And between 1998 and 2011 we'd have used `std::vector<std::vector<float> >`. This form hasn't been appropriate for almost 2 decades.

Comment: @MSalters: I believe it is not a place to argue about programming details, isn't it? This code is an example of usage - instead of any pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

If you interleave your data you will have hard time adding new entries. Otherwise it make no differences.